# adding the values of members of a class to an array c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, class, append

I have create a class, islands, for which i have created 7 instances in the main class. Each instance has an in assigned, which represents how many containers need to be picked up from each.

```
class Program
{
    public static int[,] TEUlayer1 = new int[4, 4] { { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 } };

    public static int[,] TEUlayer2 = new int[4, 4] { { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 0 } };

    public static Island is1 = new Island(2);
    public static Island is2 = new Island(3);
    public static Island is3 = new Island(1);
    public static Island is4 = new Island(4);
    public static Island is5 = new Island(2);
    public static Island is6 = new Island(2);
    public static Island is7 = new Island(1);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(TEUlayer1[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(TEUlayer2[i, j] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

    }
}

class Island
{
    public int S8s4collection { get; set; }

    public Island(int s8s)
    {
        s8s = S8s4collection;
    }
}
```

it is probably worth ignoring the main method and TEUlayer1/2 parts. these represent a stack of containers on a small ship, but this isn't relevant to the question.
My question is can I create a loop, or some other function, that goes through each instance of the island class (`is1`, `is2` ...) and appends the value associated with it to a list or array etc?
thanks!

Comment: Your class definition of Island makes no sense. It's backwards. You're saying instantiate an Island and pass in an int (what does s8s stand for? You should have clearer variable names). You then override that value with a default (since it's an int, it can't be null and thusly is 0) of S8s4collection. If your goal is to simply pass that number into the property, flip it around. Though you are using the words collection in it's name, so I'd imagine it should be a newly instantiated list or array of something, not just a single int.

Comment: Long story short, you have some fundamental issues here that without further clarification we can't even begin to help you with. If this is a typo in your code, clear that up, but for now I'm voting to close for being unclear.

Comment: S8s4collection  is NOT a collection or array, first of all. Maybe you should start there and then edit your question w/the updates.

Answer (score 2):

To be able to iterate over your islands you need a collection of Islands.

This works:

```
public class Program
{
    public static int[,] TeuLayer1 = new int[4, 4] { { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 } };
    public static int[,] TeuLayer2 = new int[4, 4] { { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 0 } };
    public static List<Island> Islands = new List<Island> { new Island(2), new Island(3), new Island(1), new Island(4), new Island(2), new Island(2), new Island(1) };

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program.PrintLayer(Program.TeuLayer1);
        Program.PrintLayer(Program.TeuLayer2);
        Program.PrintIsland(Program.Islands);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class Island
    {
        public int S8s4collection { get; private set; }

        public Island(int s8s)
        {
            S8s4collection = s8s;
        }
    }

    private static void PrintIsland(IEnumerable<Island> islands)
    {
        var index = 0;
        foreach (var island in islands)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Island {0} has a 'S8s4collection' of: {1}", index, island.S8s4collection);
            index++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static void PrintLayer(int[,] layer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(layer[i, j] + " ");
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Although having everything as static isn't ideal. Oh and your Island constructor was wrong.

Output:

[output when running the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4kSMP.png)

Comment: Yeah apologies about that. That was a mistake. Was meant to be a comment. Since its in the answer section I've changed it into an actual answer now

Answer (score 1):

besides the problems with the islands class gilliduck mentioned, it seems. like you just want an array of islands.

```
public static Island[] is = new Island[7];
public static Island is[1] = new Island(2);
...
```

then if you wamt to loop through

```
for(int i=0;i<is.Length;i++) {
  is[i].DoSomething () ;
}
```